# Why can't I summon a small_fireball?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to summon a fire charge with a command block with this:

```
/summon small_fireball ~ ~1 ~
```

But, I am getting `Invalid command syntax`

I have also tried `smallfireball` and simply doing it in the chat window, but both give me the same message.

What is wrong? I am on Windows 10 edition, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an [unresolved bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-50049), and you can't accomplish the task at hand. For some reason, the `/summon` command won't let you use `small_fireball`.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing fireball instead of small fireball.